# KineticJS - update text layer with new mouse position

Tags: mouseevent, kineticjs

I am using the following to get the mouse position:

```
  var coordinate = 0;
............
           canvas1.addEventListener('mousemove', function (evt) {
            var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas1, evt);
            var nY = Math.round(mousePos.y);
            var nX = Math.round(mousePos.x);
            coordinate = "x=" + nX + ", y=" + nY;
            $('#pValue').val(coordinate);
        }, false);
```

It works great if I display the value in a text field; however I could not update a text layer:

```
dlayerA1Text = new Kinetic.Layer();
            var simpleTextRight = new Kinetic.Text({
                x: lOffset + (lOffset * 0.25),
                y: 15,
                text: coordinate,
                fontSize: 12,
                fontFamily: 'Calibri',
                fill: 'white',
                align: 'left'
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Edited – again!  Sorry about my incomplete answer last night – I was sleepy!]**

To get a Kinetic Text to display coordinates of mouse movements on the stage…

The stage itself does not emit mouse events, but we can use `stage.getContent` to get the stage’s DIV so we can listen for mouse events on that div:

```
$(stage.getContent()).on('mousemove', function(event){ onMousemove(event)});
```

Then in the onMousemove handler, we can get the coordinate of the mouse on the stage:

```
var pos=stage.getMousePosition();
var mouseX=parseInt(pos.x);
var mouseY=parseInt(pos.y);
```

And finally we update the kinetic text to show that coordinate:

```
simpleTextRight.setText("Mouse: x="+mouseX+", y="+mouseY);
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/KamDV/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.3-beta.js"></script>

<style>
    #container{ border:solid 1px #ccc; margin-top: 10px; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

        // create a stage and a layer
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: 'container',
            width: 300,
            height: 300
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        stage.add(layer);

        // a kinetic text object to display coordinates
        var mouseToText=new Kinetic.Text({
            x:20,
            y:30,
            fontFamily:"Arial",
            fontSize:18,
            fill:"blue",
            stroke:null,
            text:"Mouse position"
        });
        layer.add(mouseToText);

        // Start listening to mousemove events
        // The stage does not emit mouse events
        // So stage.getContent() will get a reference to the stage <div>
        // This will let us get mouseevents even on areas not filled with kinetic nodes
        $(stage.getContent()).on('mousemove', function(event){ onMousemove(event)}); 


        // on mousemove...
        // Find the current mouse position
        // Update the kinetic text for the new coordinate
        // And redraw the layer
        function onMousemove(event) {

            // Find the position of the mouse relative to the stage
            var pos=stage.getMousePosition();
            mouseX=pos.x;
            mouseY=pos.y;

            // update the kinetic text with the current coordinate
            mouseToText.setText("Mouse: x="+mouseX+", y="+mouseY);

            // draw the layer with the new text
            layer.drawScene();
        }

}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes I did add it to the stage, updating the value of coordinate is the problem, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work, here it is http://jsfiddle.net/user373721/NJ7q8/7/

Comment: I tried simpleTextRight.setText but did not update the value of x and y, thanks

Comment: Thanks a million Mark, you help is very much appreciated. It works great.

Comment: For KineticJS >=5.0.0, change `getMousePosition()` to `getPointerPosition()`.

Answer (score 1):

This was very helpful.
However, the latest version of kinetic.js no longer has 'getMousePosition', they are using the 'getPointerPosition'.

Which is nice, because I could not get hand.js to work with kinetic.js. Appears they already thought of that.