# KineticJs Mouse Move error

Tags: javascript, jquery, kineticjs

I have been trying to get mouse location returned on "mousemove" in KineticJs stage.
My thought was to use add a jQuery event handler on the stage object...

I ran into a problem with this however with an error....

**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

I though i was doing something wrong so i found an example on here :p

[KineticJS - update text layer with new mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128431/kineticjs-update-text-layer-with-new-mouse-position)

It works with an old library version however, I got the same problem when i used the same code in the example with updated KineticJs library.

```
<script src="Scripts/kinetic-v5.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KamDV/30/
 (Updated Library version)

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API changes in v5. `getMousePosition()` -> `getPointerPosition()`

http://jsfiddle.net/KamDV/31/